# Check return true fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue that's killing me. Here's my code:

```
$('.somediv.btn-2').live('click', function() {
    if (addToCart()) {
        var container = $(this).parent();
        container.hide();
        container.next().show();
    }
});

function addToCart() {
    // ...
    return true
}
```

For some reason the container never gets hidden.

Although if I just hide it without the `if()` it works. The function makes an AJAX call and returns `true` on success. When I look at the calls they do return a success so it should return true.

Thanks so much.

EDIT:
I tried looking on the console with console.log(addToCart()) and it shows undefined

Comment: you'll need a semicolon after `return true`

Comment: How can your addToCart function return synchronously true on success ?  This doesn't seem possible...

Comment: So you're saying that addToCart() does in fact return TRUE?

Comment: Without the actual code and context we're guessing; "true" generally evaluates to "true" in most browsers.

Comment: You use ajax in function addToCart() ? if so that's the problem.

Comment: Seen your edit : it confirms what I supposed (see previous comment) and thus the solution I propose.

Comment: you should post your code of addToCart

Comment: @SomeKittens Not really; JS's optional semicolons should not be an issue here.

Comment: Still, one should be there.  I've found that relying on a compiler/interpreter to guess what I was doing results in difficult-to-find errors, so I add them as best practice.  It probably won't fix his problem, which is why I added it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `addToCart()` function is asynchronous you need to use a callback instead of a return value.  Your code should look something like this:

```
$('.somediv.btn-2').live('click', function() {
    addToCart(function() {
        var container = $(this).parent();
        container.hide();
        container.next().show();
    });
});

function addToCart(successCallback) {
    // instead of return true you'd have
    successCallback();
}
```

Comment: Why woudln't a async return true?

Comment: The initial thread executes before your asynchronous operation completes, so the return value is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a function returning synchronously true on success of an asynchronous AJAX call.

Pass a callback as the ajax success function like this

```
success: function () {
    var container = $(this).parent();
    container.hide();
    container.next().show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just send the contents of your "if" block as a callback method to invoke once the ajax call in addToCart is finished on success?

So your code would look more like this:

```
$('.somediv').live('click', function() {
   $.ajax({
        .
        .
        success: function() {
              var container = $(this).parent();
               .
               .
         }
    });
  });
```